# Which facility upgrade unlocks maneuver nodes in KSP

Tags: kerbal-space-program

Which [facility upgrade](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/0.90.0#KSC_Facility_Upgrade_Effects) unlocks [maneuver nodes](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Maneuver_node) in career mode in KSP?

The [beta announcement](http://forum.kerbalspaceprogram.com/content/323-The-KSP-Beta-Than-Ever-FAQ) hints that maneuver nodes are now unlocked with a facility upgrade:

> **Are there any perks for upgrading?**
>
> The building in question
>   will upgrade visually, both from the outside and the inside. More
>   gameplay mechanics will be also be unlocked as the player progresses
>   through the different building tiers. For example, allowing EVAs in
>   space or being able to use maneuver nodes in the map view.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to upgrade 2 buildings: the tracking station (to level 2) and the mission control (to level 2).

Just one by itself is not enough. If you upgrade mission control without the tracking station, you'll see a message telling you that "flight planning" is not available until the tracking station is upgraded.

Comment: It's actually the _second_ level of mission control (and tracking center). You don't need to upgrade mission control to level three.

Answer (score 5):

As of 0.90 maneuver nodes are unlocked by buying the first upgrade to the **Tracking Station**.

Comment: Level 2 being the second upgrade? The first upgrade says it will show patched conics.

Comment: No, all facilities start on level 1. The first upgrade brings them to level 2. "Patched Conics" are a synonym for maneuver nodes. I clarified this.

Answer (score 4):

Mission Control (the place where you get contracts) the upgrade is called "flight planning".  The tracking station lets you unlock conics which I think are simply the predictions of intercepting celestial bodies, etc.  I unlocked the tracking station first, which gave me the blue/purple lines etc. but no ability to place maneuver nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You have to unlock both the second level Tracking Station ***and*** the second level Mission Control. You are looking for the "Flight Planning" upgrade.

Note that it is the *second* level of each building, not the *third*. Neither building needs the third level upgrade before maneuver nodes are available.

Comment: This does not add anything to the original answer.

Comment: As I said: "I would comment or upvote but I do not have enough rep yet" -- how do I get enough rep to start contributing?  (apparently I can comment on my own answers but not others until I get 50?!? rep)

Comment: Also, someone should comment on Patrick's answer to say that only the level 2 upgrade is needed for each building, not level 3.

Comment: At this point, you should just observe and thank people when you can, but NOT in the answer section. This is not a QA forum, the answer section is purely for answers.

Comment: "observe" -- got that, been doing that for quite a while, i.e. a few years because Stack Exchange comes up a lot when Googling answers to programming questions.

"thank people" -- um, how? I cannot comment until I get enough rep. Cannot offer help in the form of upvoting good answers or commenting on good answers (that might benefit from a little elaboration or minor correction).

Comment: @MichaelW Rep is earned by asking good questions, answering helpfully, and by suggesting helpful edits to other posts. [It only takes a little bit of rep to start participating in other ways.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges) Because we're exclusively Q&A though, people have to show they can do the Q&A part before we let them get distracted by any other features. :)

Comment: @michaelw +1 your clarification helped me, thank you.

Comment: @MichaelW thanks for your contribution.